# ASP.NET Authentication asking to login for default page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I added authentication forms to my ASP.NET project. The main page (default.aspx in my case) should not be password protected, so I added this line to the web.config:

```
<location path="default.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The problem is that when I enter the URL, say http://mywebapp.university.edu/, I got the login page. Sure enough, if I enter http://mywebapp.university.edu/default.aspx. then I got to the page without having to provide any credential. What can I do so if I enter the URL I get served the default.aspx page without having to enter it explicitly on the url?

Thanks!

Comment: So I came up with this horrible hack on the Login.aspx page:

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == "/")
            {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
        }

Now it works. If anybody knows how to fix this I still accept answers, and of course a better, more elegant solution will be picked as the selected answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user directly goes to the `default` page he will be `verified` using `user.identity` if not he will be `redirected` to `Login page`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // if the user is already logged in
     {
          Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
     }
     else
     {    
          Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
     }
}
```

Comment: And this would be helpful how?

Comment: The OP is saying that the user does NOT need to be logged in.  The user is being prompted for credentials when they shouldn't.

Comment: @DotNetter, to me that reads as, redirect to login if they are already logged in.

Comment: @Ash-Updated.Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS , go to website property as given in below link

```
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true
```

Move up default.aspx page above the login page , save and test.

Comment: default.aspx was already at the top of the default documents. That was the first thing I tried. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I have setup a website like this and it works fine for me. did you check if any Redirect url is given on the website?  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Does your web.config or code has any Rewriting rules written?

Comment: I have no redirects whatsoever, this is a very simple website.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this horrible hack on the Login.aspx page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == "/")
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Now it works. If anybody knows how to fix this I still accept answers, thanks!